# APNS feedback return random device token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, ruby, apple-push-notifications, feedback

I have some problem using the feedback service of APNS, everytime I call the service I receive only one exactly token and everytime is different! What these tokens mean?
I've tried both development and production mode, I also tried with registering two devices, uninstalls a device and call the feedback API but still I receive one token that it's different every time.

My ruby code to connect is:

```
  cert = File.read(options[:cert])
  ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
  ctx.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(cert, options[:passphrase])
  ctx.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(cert)
  sock = TCPSocket.new(ENV['IOS_SERVER_APN_FEEDBACK'], ENV['IOS_PORT_APN_FEEDBACK'])

  ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock, ctx)
  ssl.sync = true
  ssl.connect

  while line = sock.read(38) 
    time, length = line.unpack("Nn")
    puts line.unpack("x6H#{length << 1}").first
  end

  ssl.close
  sock.close
```

Everytime I try to execute this code I receive this output:

```
  852a38d14b5e6df4168d3f7f41b38f6627b2cc0605bd53266f6d6fe8332738
  d88cd573c0a8f521ad10c8cab863575972c6a24140447f62073dc40e12df20
  225393b20754363b93712fb15f4d7a5891d93b27a5b5855fdccf88dcdc82a4
  (are three output of three different executions)
```

But this are not tokens of uninstalled devices...what can be?